# JPA find and update strategy

Tags: jpa, find, entitymanager, named-query

In my JPA implementation, I do a em.find() to select a list of objects and modify these objects.Next, I update these modified objects calling em.merge() inside a transaction ( TX in order to persist other related stuffs).

This works great except for the fact that SELECT is happening twice ( once during find and other during other) which I feel is redundant and performance killer in my case.

I would be reluctant to bring find() within transaction boundary of em.merge() even if by doing so would solve the latter SELECT.

Is defining my own NamedQuery the only way to update these objects without issuing another SELECT?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify where happens the second SELECT?

Comment: Why are you reluctant to bring the find() call into your tran? What provider are you using?

Comment: @Rick Select takes few minutes to execute(because of non indexed column querying). The additional time for Select execution times the Transaction out ( JBOSS limitation of 5 min). I could potentially increase the time but keeping this as a last resport option.

Comment: @perissf Second SElECT happens during the call to merge()

Comment: In your situation I'd consider the possibility to restructure the db schema

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JTA managed EntityManager then each transaction boundary will be a new persistence context, and unless you have a shared cache configured, you will have to go back to the database.

What JPA provider are you using?  If you are using EclipseLink, a shared cache is enabled by default.

For JPA transactions, if you use the same EntityManager for the find and merge, then it should still be in the persistence context.

Comment: I am using Hibernate as the JPA provider. In my code, Entitiymanager is defined as an instance variable within the DAO.DAO is referenced using @EJB in my bean containing business logic. Here I am calling dao.find() and dao.merge() . Does this mean I am using different EM for every dao call?